# What's the difference between jenkinsci and jenkins on Docker Hub?

Tags: docker, jenkins

What's the difference between jenkinsci and jenkins user on Docker Hub? Both seems to maintain Jenkins images in hub.
https://hub.docker.com/u/jenkins/
https://hub.docker.com/u/jenkinsci/

Answer (score 0):

Some `jenkinsci` images are deprecated (see for example description of [`jenkinsci/jenkins`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jenkins/)) and must be replaced by `jenkins` images (for example, [`jenkins/jenkins`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/) for the previous example).

`jenkins` repository is the new official one, if I believe [this commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/commit/a8b3b9c87b0536e4d8ab776ee1c03370810195eb) on [Docker official Jenkins repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker). Also, check the [issue on GitHub to deprecate `jenkinsci`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/515).

Comment: Google suggested to me that the preferred starting point was jenkinsci/blueocean. Is that also deprecated? One difference between them is that jenkinsci/blueocean is based on alpine linux which has a smaller footprint where jenkins/jenkins is based on a full distro.